# How does Stripe's prorating work?

Tags: stripe-payments, recurring-billing

From Stripe's documentation under updating a user's subscription plan:

> By default, we prorate subscription changes. For example, if a customer signs up on May 1 for a $10 plan, she'll be billed $10 immediately. If she then switches to a $20 plan on May 15, on June 1 she'll be billed $25 ($20 for a renewal of her subscription and a $5 prorating adjustment for the previous month).

Shouldn't the charge on June 1st be $30; $20 for the renewal and $10 (half of $20 because half of May) for the previous month? Did Stripe get their calculations confused, or am I dead wrong on how prorating works?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a company's policy, not their API.

Comment: However, If they paid $10 for May in the beginning of May, then changed to a $20 plan halfway through the month, then they still owe $5 for the 2nd half of May when the June billing is processed.

Comment: Right, I just figured this out too. The prorate amount is calculated by subtracting half of the previous month's plan (which is $10/2 = $5) from half of the new plan (which is $20/2 = $10); $10 - $5 = $5 prorate adjustment.

I'd say this post should be kept for others to see, incase they trip up on the math in the same way that I did.

Comment: `(new_plan - old_plan)*(days_since_switch/days_in_last_month)`

Comment: @sam thank you for making this question! :clap::clap:

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Another way to look at it is:

For the two months the customer should pay

```
$5 for May 1 to 15
+ $10 for May 16 to 31
+ $20 for June
= $35 total
- $10 already paid
= $25
```